# Why 0 is equal to empty string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I need some help in finding why the following `T-SQL` statement returns `1` (true):

```
SELECT IIF( 0 = '', 1, 0)
```

I guess someone has change an `ANSI` option like `SET ANSI_NULLS` or something else that is causing the behavior.

My issue is that I am joining some values and in the final row set I have values which are joined by `0` and `''` values, which is not correct.

Comment: I don't know if this would help in your joining issue, but in general, you can use this to distinguish between `0` and empty strings: `SELECT LENGTH(0); -- returns 1. // SELECT LENGTH(''); -- returns 0;`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That is just documented behavior. I don't think anyone messed with the settings.

See [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) on MSDN.

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence.

As noted in the comments the empty string gets converted to 0 in any numeric type and to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 when converted to a date.

EDIT: I think your real problem is that your design is so that you have to join on fields of a different data type. The only way to get around this is to have a convert on your join clause which will hurt query performance. The main problem is probably with the schema design

EDIT:
There was a lot of discussion in the comments that have been moved to chat. However illogical it may seem, converting an empty string to other data types produces arbitrary values.

This code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, '')
SELECT CONVERT(float, '')
SELECT CONVERT(date, '')
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '')
```

Produces this output:

```
0
0
1900-01-01
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

You could expect then that this behavior is consistent between other preceding datatypes and expect that converting 0 to a date would produce the same arbitrary value but it doesn't.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, 0)
```

Produces

> Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

Because it's not a [supported conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)

while

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 0)
```

Returns

> January, 01 1900 00:00:00

So yes, it's weird and arbitrary, but actually documented and explainable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation about this answer has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30099/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-v-why-0-is-equal-to-empty-string).

Comment: Is the behavior `CAST('' AS INT)` -> 0 documented somewhere? It would be nice if you add reference.

Comment: @SalmanA: It *should* be documented in the "Converting Character Data" section of the [char/varchar documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but it currently isn't. I have left a feedback comment asking for it to be included.

Comment: Are there any performance loss to mention if one just uses `myIntColumn ='' ` in sted of checking the datatype first and asking  `myIntColumn =0 ` inside a where statement?